# Vista: service stops just after start

Tags: windows-vista, windows-service

A service is stopping immediately after being started. The service is `cygwin sshd`  and runs under the SYSTEM account, with `cyglsa-config` for cygwin authentication. How do I diagnose this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the event viewer - error messages for the service should be logged there.

Answer (score 2):

By default, application events should be written to the Windows Application Event Log. This includes cygwin's implementation of sshd on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been answered, the Event Viewer is your friend here. As for the problem. It's not unusual for ported applications such as this to leave behind a pid file (*.pid) if the process terminates uncleanly. Upon a service restart the application will detect the pid file, assume that another instance is already running and exit accordingly. Find and manually remove the pid file and retry the service start.